# How to concatenate many numbers in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'd like to return numbers `5 6 7` in one line into the console instead of the string of "5 6 7". I want numbers as if I put `console.log(5, 6, 7)`. But if I have an array of many numbers with `console.log([5, 6, 7].join(' '))` it returns a string.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not totally clear what you're asking, but if you're using ES6 you can use the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator):

```
const myArray = [ 5, 6, 7 ];
console.log( ...myArray ); //use the es6 spread operator to turn the array into args
```

Otherwise you can use [`.apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) like this:

```
var myArray = [ 5, 6, 7 ];
console.log.apply( console, myArray ); //use myArray as the arguments
```

Comment: Spread notation isn't an operator (it can't be; an operator has a single result value). It's just syntax.

Comment: You might be right, but it's commonly referred to as the spread operator, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/reference/spread-operator-decrement-dot-dot-dot-javascript https://davidwalsh.name/spread-operator https://dmitripavlutin.com/how-three-dots-changed-javascript/

Comment: okay, three times im reading the document on spread operator and didn't understand what it do. could you please simplify it? what does it mean to expand the values to where they are expected? is it iterating over them or what?

Comment: It just tells javascript to treat the array as if you had written them as parameters in the function call. So `myFunc( ...[1, 2] )` is the same as `myFunc( 1, 2 )`.

Comment: You can also use it when declaring a function to treat parameters as if they were an array, a bit like the `arguments` keyword.

Comment: @DuncanThacker: All the more reason not to perpetuate that misinformation. Lots of people said the world was flat, too.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - isn't that itself misinformation? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myth_of_the_flat_Earth

Comment: @TJ I think the consequences of incorrect geography might be more serious than mislabeling of language features, but I suppose you're correct

Comment: @MartinSmith: :-) I didn't say **when**.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are close. Try joining values without any blank - console.log([5, 6, 7].join(''))

To verify that return value is integer and not string (Not sure why you want to do this), you can try console.log(([5,6,7].join(''))-1) and see.